# is it possible to list all types of app service using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-appservice, azure-cli2

I am trying to list the type of app service associated with particular subscription using azure cli.

Type of app service:

1. Web apps
2. logic apps
3. Function apps
4. mobile apps
5. API apps

So far I have tried to find out the individual command for these. Out of which I could only get

```
web apps : az webapp list --subscription subscriptionId 
function apps: az functionapp list --subscription subscriptionId
logic apps: az logic workflow list --subscription subscriptionId
```

I am not sure the above commands include the API apps and mobile apps or it filters.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use `az webapp list` to list mobile and api app?

Comment: ```az webapp list``` do not list function apps even though they have type : microsoft.Web/sites

Comment: `az web list` cannot list function apps. Because it filters, it will exclude the function app resource. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/ac3b6ef47840609e39e1d4d95ffe942cba9193a6/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py#L693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, API apps and Mobile apps are part of the Appservice which falls under WebApps.

You could use the [CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest) or use the [`REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/list)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `az resource list` (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az_resource_list)) and apply a query filter

```
az resource list --subscription subscriptionId --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Web/sites' || type=='Microsoft.Logic/workflows']"
```

You could update the query filter based on your need.

As mentioned by @Sajeetharan, Mobile Apps, API Apps, Web Apps and Function Apps are part of App services (Microsoft.Web/sites)